# Nav drop down showing above navbar on hover

Tags: html, css, asp.net, navbar, dropdown

drop down showing above parent navigation bar i want to show the drop down below my navigation bar
i am using asp.net site master page
page link
http://eforms.hopto.org/Management/

i just copy the code from w3shools 
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown_navbar.asp
and past to my code and still not working using chrome or Opera
but it working with microsoft Edge browser
i am using site master page and asp.net

```
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move it down with `top`... just add the `top` here:

```
.dropdown-content {
    top: 45px;
}
```

OR, add the dropdown-content **inside** the dropbtn - now they are not inside, but right after - eg:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>

    <div class="dropdown-content">
    </div>        
 </div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ,Its working now I just added top:45px